# How can I merge a LOT of polylines automatically?

Tags: merge, line

I have lots of MultiPolylines, three-dimensional arrays where the bottom level is an array of lat/lngs, the second level is an array of those points (a single polyline), and the top level is the group of lines.  Like this:

```
[
    [
        [50.12312,0.2541],
        [50.12322,0.2547],
        ...
    ],

        [52.412,1.142141],
        [51.9812,0.21237],
        ...
    ],
    ...
]
```

The polylines in each group are generally contiguous, and I would like to merge them so that connecting lines within a group become a single line.  How can I do this programmatically without some sort of desktop software?  Is there Python,PHP,JavaScript,etc. code out there for this task or do I have to write it from scratch?

Comment: Do you have PostGIS somewhere in the stack ? if so st_linemerge or ST_CollectionHomogenize are helpful functions.

Answer (score 1):

Merge overlapping should work, you would want to run on a vector layer or shapefile.
ESRI has the tool, QGIS should have the tool, or you could look at the code and whip something up if you have time on your hands. You could try merge and dissolve operations as well depending on the sequence of proceedures. Try ArcGIS documentation to research the scope of your problem and range of possible options, and would likely apply to open source packages, conceptualy.

Answer (score 1):

where you get this data? file , database or webservice ?

What i would do : Upload data to postgis , fix it there and use it from there.

If you want to create your own code then there is [JTS](http://www.vividsolutions.com/jts/jtshome.htm) for JAVA, [Pysal](http://code.google.com/p/pysal/)  for Python etc.

Answer (score 0):

The Shapely Python Package can merge linear features. Look at method shapely.ops.linemerge(lines). It merges all contiguous elements of lines.